# spring boot + hibernate table names queried in lower case

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring boot and hibernate.

Below is my application prop file and the naming strategy implementation file.
When I try to push data to DB the below exception occurs **ERROR: relation "nickname" does not exist.**

I want access table name and column name always in uppercase.

Please help me to understand what went wrong.[image]

**NickName.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NICKNAME")
public class NickName {
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.239.129:5432/maindb
spring.datasource.username=pgdbuser
spring.datasource.password=pgdbuser
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

> **PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable{

    public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
         String nameModified = StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText());

        // Do whatever you want with the name modification
        return new Identifier(nameModified, name.isQuoted());
    }


    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        String nameModified = StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText());

        // Do whatever you want with the name modification
        return new Identifier(nameModified, name.isQuoted());
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
.......
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "nickname" does not exist
  Position: 460
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
```

**Update 1: changed app.prop file as below**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.239.129:5432/maindb
spring.datasource.username=pgdbuser
spring.datasource.password=pgdbuser
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.theroot.rester.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
```

**Note :**

In my sql client just now checked

```
select * from "NICKNAME"; --Works
select * from NICKNAME; --doesn't Work
```

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` <-- change this line to make this parameter point to the new class: `PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl`

Comment: @krokodilko update the question . Thanks

Comment: So you must create your tables using double quotes - `CREATE TABLE "TABLE_NAME" (....)`, see this demo to learn how postgresql create table command works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/81c0a/1

Comment: yes I think that causing the issue, will check and come back.. will remove double quotes and try

Comment: yes removing double quotes in column names (in sql DDLs) solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

1) Get rid of `PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.java`

2) Make changes in application.properties as below :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= 
org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

3) In `@Table` add schema as well. ie., `@Table(name="table", schema="schemaname")`

This worked for me with Postgresql 10 with Hibernate 5.x and Spring Boot 2.1.x.  If you are using an older version of Postgresql, then use appropriate PostgreSqlxxDialect from Spring.